# AngularJS + Routing + Resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'm getting this error:

> Error: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.7/$injector/unpr?p0=HttpResponseProvider%20%3C-%20HttpResponse%20%3C-%20DealerLeads
>
> Injector Unknown provider

Here's my router (ui.router):

```
$stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: "/main",
            templateUrl: "views/main.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Main Page' }
        })
        .state('leads', {
            url: "/leads",
            templateUrl: "views/leads.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Dealer Leads' },
            controller: 'DealerLeads',
            resolve: DealerLeads.resolve
        })
```

Here's my Controller:

```
function DealerLeads($scope, HttpResponse) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(HttpResponse));
}
```

Here's my resolve:

```
DealerLeads.resolve = {
    HttpResponse: function ($http) {
...
    }
}
```

The data is getting to the controller, I see it in the alert. However, after the controller is done, during the rendering of the view (I think), the issue seems to be happening.

The final rendered view has two controllers: One main controller in the body tag, and the second controller 'DealerLeads' inside of that. I've tried removing the main controller, and the issue is still present.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any more code that is necessary to understand/resolve the issue?

Comment: `One main controller in the body tag, and the second controller 'DealerLeads' inside of that` --> Are you using `DealerLeads`  with ng-controller? or leaving it to the router to instantiate it? Please show  the full error message?

Comment: They're both declared respectively in their own tags:
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-controller="DealerLeads as leads">

Comment: It is wrong, you cannot do that

Comment: OK, so what should I be doing?

Comment: I've never seen the usage of Controller properties as part of the resolve. I'm not 100% certain it isn't going to work, but given your error message I'm thinking not. Try replacing the resolve property with "normal" syntax and see if that works.

Comment: Regarding second comment. The controller you define in your route will be set for the entire scope of your ui-view element. So in other words you are duplicating it.

Comment: What is normal syntax? I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting

Comment: Yes, So, I've tried removing the main controller declaration in the body tag, and I was still receiving the same error. Meaning that there was only one controller in the DOM

Comment: @KGChristensen It is not just about duplicating, you just cannot instantiate it because of the resolve dependency. And infact there is no problem with the way resolve is provided provided the constructor is accessibly in the place where the route is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use route resolve argument as dependency injection in the controller bound to the route, you cannot use that controller with `ng-controller` directive because the service provider with the name `HttpResponse` does not exist. It is a dynamic dependency that is injected by the router when it instantiates the controller to be bound in its respective partial view.

Just remove the `ng-controller="DealerLeads"` from the view and make sure that view is part of the html rendered by the state `leads` @ `templateUrl: "views/leads.html",`. Router will bind it to the the template for you resolving the dynamic dependency `HttpResponse`. If you want to use controllerAs you can specify that in the router itself as:-

```
controller: 'DealerLeads',
controllerAs: 'leads' //Not sure if this is supported by ui router yet
```

or

```
controller: 'DealerLeads as leads',
```

Also when you do:

```
.state('leads', {
        url: "/leads",
        templateUrl: "views/leads.html",
        data: { pageTitle: 'Dealer Leads' },
        controller: 'DealerLeads',
        resolve: DealerLeads.resolve
    })
```

make sure that `DealerLeads` is accessible at the place where the route is defined. It would be a better practice to move the route definition to its own controller file so that they are all in one place. And whenever possible especially in a partial view of a route it is better to get rid of `ng-controller` starting the directive and instead use route to instantiate and bind the controller for that template. It gives more re-usability in terms of the view as a whole not being tightly coupled with a controller name and instead only with its contract. So i would not worry about removing `ng-controller` directive where router can instantiate the controller.

Comment: Thank YOU!!!! Thank you! I've been struggling with this for the past 6 hours and re-written so much code, my brain hurts!

Comment: @Q-Ball You are welcome, hope i could provide some insights.. :)

Comment: Yes. I'm fairly new to this and learning as I go along. Many of the blocks for me occur on nuances like these. In all my searches today, I have not found any place that specifically states not to explicitly set the ng-controller attribute. And that it automatically binds it to the view

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely understand you question, and also not an expert as @PSL in angular.

If you just want to pass some data into the controller, maybe below code can help you.

I copied a piece of code from the project:

```
.state('masthead.loadTests.test',{
    url: '/loadTests/:id',
    templateUrl: 'load-tests/templates/load-test-entity.tpl.html',
    controller: 'loadTestEntityCtrl',
    data: { pageTitle: 'loadTests',
        csh: '1005'
    },
    resolve: {
        // Get test entity data before enter to the page (need to know running state)
        LoadTestEntityData: [
            '$stateParams',
            '$state',
            'LoadTestEntity',
            'LoggerService',
            '$rootScope',
            function ($stateParams, $state, LoadTestEntity, LoggerService, $rootScope) {
                // Get general data
                return LoadTestEntity.get({id: $stateParams.id},function () {
                },
                    // Fail
                    function () {
                        // When error navigate to homepage
                        LoggerService.error('error during test initiation');
                        $state.go('masthead.loadTests.list', {TENANTID: $rootScope.session.tenantId});
                    }).$promise;
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Here the LoadTestEntityData is the data we injected into the controller, 
LoadTestEntity and LoggerService are services needed for building the data.

```
.factory('LoadTestEntity', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        '/api/xxx/:id',
        {id: '@id'},
        {
            create: {method: 'POST'},
            update: {method: 'PUT'}
        }
    );
}])
```

Hope it helps!