# AngularJS [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dataProvider <- data <- PageCtrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen the other answers and so far nothing has helped me. I get this error with the following code in a file:

```
   angular.module('myApp.page', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/page/:pageId', {
                templateUrl: 'page/view.html',
                controller: 'PageCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    data: function($q, $http, $routeParams) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://....' + $routeParams.pageId})
                            .then(function(data) {
                            deferred.resolve(data);


       });
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            }
        })
    }])
    .controller('PageCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, data) {
//do stuff
}
```

And in the app.js I have this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngResource',
    'myApp.page'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]).
config(['$provide', Decorate])
```

Everything was working correctly and I fetched the data with the HTTP method with no problems, until I started using the Q library and moved the data fetching into the config section. Any tips? None of the other answers seem to work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error makes it sound like ChannelCtrl is supposed to have a property called data injected into it. What does that have to do w/the code you're showing?

Comment: `data` is a dynamic dependency injected by the router (based on the resolve properties) when instantiating the controller while rendering its respective route. If you instead use `PageCtrl` (oh wait did OP mean to use `ChannelCtrl`) with ng-controller you will get that error for the non existent dependency called `data`. Also  `PageCtrol != PageCtrl` also `PageCtrl != channelCtrl` so there could be many typoes causing this issue as well.

Comment: @PSL sorry, I changed some names when making the post. I've edited again and now it is correct, as is in my PC. The problem still ocurrs, putting aside a typo.

Comment: are you instantiating `PageCtrl` anywhere else? Using `ng-controller` or via directive?

Comment: @LuísFerreira  did you note my comment `If you instead use PageCtrl  with ng-controller you will get that error`

Comment: @PSL You mean if I use ng-controller in the view with PageCtrl? Because I do that. It was done like that before with no problems (the only problem like I said was after I moved the HTTP call to the promise). Could that be the problem? But then how do I have a controller to put the data in my view?

Comment: @DanPantry No, I don't instantiate it anywhere else. In my view I use it with ng-controller, and inside I have a ng-repeat for the data. That data came from an HTTP call in the controller, and then I moved that HTTP call into the "resolve" as seen here, and that is when the problems started.

Comment: @LuísFerreira yes you cannot use it with ng-controller directive anymore and you dont have to because router will manage the instantiation of the controller for you by specifying the controller in it. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205914/angularjs-routing-resolve/28206020#28206020), though this answer is specific to ui router same is applicable to router as well.

Comment: @PSL Thank you very much. It seems I was searching for the wrong thing. Unfortunately I can only test this tomorrow, but I guess that's it. Is there any way to credit you for this if it works (which I guess it will)?

Comment: @LuísFerreira haha give it a try first and you don't have to credit me :)

Comment: @PSL thank you very much, that was it! If you submit your answer here I'll accept it as correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You issue is due to the fact that you are using `ng-controller` directive to instantiate the controller `PageCtrl` which takes a dynamic dependency `data` which is only created by the router. So when you inject a dynamic dependency via router resolve and having the router instantiate the controller, you do not need to and should not instantiate the controller via `ng-controller` it will simply fail due to the lack of dependency availability from the injector. router will manage the instantiation of the controller and setting it up for the respective view for you.

*So just remove ng-controller from your view* also make sure the partial represented by the route is complete enough to represent the view related to the controller functionality. Also i have seen it is a good practice not to start with a partial view with `ng-controller` and instantiate with route which will help making that partial view more reusable with a different controller. Also while creating a unit test you can easily mock the dynamic dependency and feed it via the `$controller` service.

Comment: quite away from angular.js these days?

Comment: @A.B haha yeah it has been a while.. :)