# Can't get Angularjs to wait for data before rendering template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, firebase

I have looked on many tutorials and stack overflow pages but none of the solution work for me. Basically, I need to get data from firebase before passing that data to the template. This may or may not be important but I am using nodejs and ejs on the backend. But the problem is with Angular 1

Code

```
angular.module("example", ["elif", "ngRoute"])


.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/leaders", {
            templateUrl: "leaders",
            controller: 'LeadersController',
            resolve: {
                data: function () {
                    return getLeadersData();
                }
            }
        });

    }])


.controller('LeadersController', ["$scope", "$http", "$location", "$window", 'data',
    function($scope, $http, $location, $window, data)
    {
        $scope.data = data;
    }]);

function getLeadersData()
{
  // firebase does its thing and returns data fine here, it is an array of objects where each object has a few things in it
}
```

but I have redone this code about 15 times or more using different guides and I get the same errors over and over. the most common same error I get is

```
"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dataProvider <- data <- LeadersController
```

I have no clue at this point what to do.

EDIT: added html, this html is the basic webpage, with other stuff deleted, the exact error happens with this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/flickerFix.css">
    <script src="/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <title>Leaders</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/nav.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/leaders.css" />
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.9/firebase.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="/angular/angular.js"></script>-->
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" data-semver="1.3.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js" ></script>
        <script data-require="angular-route@1.3.0" data-semver="1.3.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
    <!-- angular fire not used -->
        <script src="/angularfire/angularfire.js"></script>
        <script src="/elif/elif.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/angular/LeadersController.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="example">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper" >
            <p id="header">Leaders</p>
            <div class="container" ng-controller="LeadersController" >
                <h1>name:  {{ leaders[0].name }}</h1>
                <h1>name:  {{ JSON.stringify(leaders)}}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks similar to issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30107574/angularjs-injectorunpr-unknown-provider-dataprovider-data-pagectrl

Comment: Refer to the updated Plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/3SsQGRnRpryCHzYF5mKB?p=preview) and make sure you are not using ng-controller in your HTML. Also how ng-view being used refer https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp for details

Answer (score 1):

You have no controller or module name 'data' loaded

Comment: Can you explain how to do so? I've been going off tutorials and I haven't seen anything else that I think it's not already in my code so if it's okay can you help guide me

Comment: The problem is in the .controller('LeadersController', ["$scope", "$http", "$location", "$window", 'data',
    function($scope, $http, $location, $window, data)
    {
        
    }]); when you remove both the 'data'  and data from this bit of code, the error should be gone.

Comment: I will try this as soon as i get on my laptop but odd enough every example i seen did it this way. Bascially they wpuld do

Comment: $scope.data = data; or on other modifications to it something like $scope.data = data.getData() assuming a function was returned not the actually data

Answer (score 0):

add code for service, constant or other thing or remove `data` parameter.

put `getLeadersData` function to service called 'data' and then use it to pass your database data to controller and view.

in template you can use ng-if directive to render part of template when you get your `data`ready

**EDIT WIT SAMPLE CODE**
if You want to use angular in the future You must learn about use of services. Services are one of the most important parts in Angular.

```
.controller('LeadersController', ["$scope", "$http", "$location", "$window", 'data', function($scope, $http, $location, $window, data)
    {
        $scope.leaders = data.getLeadersData();
        // data being passed in but not used just yet, I get error without it
    }])
.service('data',[function(){
     return {
getLeadersData : function()
    {
      return 'data';
    }
     }
    }])
```

Comment: I'm still very new to angular can you show me some example code

Comment: If You donn't make it works - prepare plunker and I help You tomorrow.

Comment: @Dominik, Calling the function in controller defeats the original issue of the problem i.e. To wait for data before rendering template

Comment: @MechanicalCoder not if He use ng-if to wait until have data in controller, or use promise in service.

Comment: And in question is ` I need to get data from firebase before passing that data to the template.` so my code will fork for that

Comment: Do you guys need to see the html?

Comment: @DominikRuczyński  tested it, the code above, and the results back from  data.getLeadersData(); is undefined

Comment: Added html to original post

Comment: I added return to `getLeadersData` so now it shouldn't return undefined. Please let me know if it works for You.