# Angular not binding data on html directly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I'm a beginner in Angular (ver 1.6.3) and i ran into this problem:

i have a controller called prof:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.prof', [])
        .controller('ProfController', ProfController);

    /** @ngInject */
    function ProfController($scope, Data)
    {
        var vm = this;
        vm.documents = Data.documents;
        vm.classes = Data.classes;
    }
})();
```

Here's its associated module :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.prof')
        .config(config);

    /** @ngInject */
    function config($stateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider, msApiProvider) {
        // State
        $stateProvider
            .state('app.prof', {
                url    : '/prof',
                views  : {
                    'content@app': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/main/prof/prof.html',
                        controller : 'ProfController as vm'
                    }
                },
                resolve : {
                    Data : function(msApi){
                        return msApi.resolve('data@get');
                    }
                }
            });

        $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('app/main/prof');
        msApiProvider.register('data', ['app/data/prof/prof-data.json']);
    }
})();
```

And here's the main problem : i have this html :

```
<div class="document" ng-repeat="document in vm.documents">
    <ms-card template="'app/custom-directives/prof-card/prof-card.html'"
             ng-model="document"></ms-card>
</div>
```

it works perfectly fine, the data is correctly binded and all, but when i put the template called directly in the page instead of calling it throught a `<ms-card>` it doesn't work anymore ! 
i've tried to put some `console.log()` a little eveywhere but it always says the data isn't defined; i don't get it. 
Plus, the `ng-repeat` always works fine

Edit : a bit of the html i call :

```
<md-list-item class="document-item md-white-bg md-2-line" md-ink-ripple>
              <div class="media ml-16">
                <img class="image-apercu" ng-src="{{card.media.image.src}}" alt="{{card.media.image.alt}}" ng-show="card.media.image">
              </div>
```

ps : when i add the html directly i don't forget to put the `ng-model="document"` but it still doesn't work

This is very confusing for me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind the "vm" object with "$scope".  you need to bind it with Scope like

```
function ProfController($scope, Data)
    {
        //$scope.vm = this;

        $scope.vm.documents = Data.documents;
        $scope.vm.classes = Data.classes;
    }
```

Your Html Should be like :

```
<body ng-app="app.prof" ng-controller="ProfController">
    <div class="document" ng-repeat="document in vm.documents">
        <ms-card template="'app/custom-directives/prof-card/prof-card.html'"
                 ng-bind="document"></ms-card>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: if i write this directly vm isn't defined anymore ?

Comment: @Orsu Yes within ProfController vm isn't defined anymore

Comment: i'm sorry, it's not clear to me : if i write your code vm isn't defined anymore, the whole thing falls apart

Comment: ohh Sorry this should be  $scope.vm.documents = Data.documents; i forget $scope with vm

Comment: ooooh yeah that was very confusing to me. Still the data isn't being binded, do i call it badly in the html ? (i've added a bit of the code in the question)

Comment: i just applied your changes, now i get "Unknow provider : DataProvider <- Data <- ProfController"

Comment: Remove ng-controller from your View

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30107574/angularjs-injectorunpr-unknown-provider-dataprovider-data-pagectrl

Comment: done ! the error is gone, but now in my elements i have "[object Object]" like the data isn't correctly displayed (thank you for helping me so far)

Comment: @Orsu please marrk my answer as helpful and vote up if this work for you

Comment: try it ng-bind="document.YourPropertyName"

Comment: like, i put a "ng-bind='document.PropertyUsed'" in each element where i use a "{{propety}}" ?

Answer (score 0):

In the end i found myself - I put the controller back like it was, i renamed all the `{{card.something}}` as `{{document.something}}` and i removed the `ng-bind=""` in the `<div>` that was being looped.